# Combine native mobile development with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android

Assume we have implemented mobile apps for different platforms (iOS/Android/Winfon(in future)). All applications have some common business logic.

For example, calculator application: user inputs two digits and our application should be able to add them. So in each application we will have some class to make the addition. Something like this (written in c# just for demonstration):

```
class CalculatorService
{
    public int Add(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }
}
```

Each application will duplicate this logic. The goal is to avoid such duplication.

After some research I drew attention to Xamarin.  And now I`d like to have one library that is built with Xamarin and written in c# that will be referenced and used by different mobile applications. But still, I don't want to completely port my applications to Xamarin (For example, my calculator applications are developed by my friend and I would like to keep him busy in this new flow).

So, to make things short: is it possible to develop mobile applications in native manner, but to move business logic to separate c#-xamarin libraries? And if yes, then how complex will it be?

Or if I will use Xamarin than I'm doomed to port existing solutions to c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only technical requirement Xamarin poses is that the app's entry point must be the managed Main method (Xamarin provides the native main method, and needs to run code at that point).

An extreme example (but perfectly possible) would to only have one managed method (Main), which calls into your own native library to do everything else.

Both Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android have support for using custom native libraries, the workflow you'd have would be to create native libraries from your native code, which is then consumed in a Xamarin.iOS|Android project.

[Binding iOS libraries for Xamarin.iOS](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/)
[Binding Android libraries for Xamarin.Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_(.jar)/)